# How to create dynamic json path (object coming from Angular component)

Tags: json, angular

I have created a models.json file like this:

```
    {
       "bmw":{
          "mtl":"assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.mtl",
          "obj":"assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.obj"
       },
       "bugatti":{
          "mtl":"assets/bugatti/bugatti.mtl",
          "obj":"assets/bugatti/bugatti.obj"
       }
    }
```

I have 2 dynamic variable(file & file_type) coming from a dropdown of a component(ex - bmw, obj). I logged **this.file** && **this.file_type** and its coming fine.

I have imported models.json file in *my.component.ts" successfully.

I am trying to create a dynamic path so that I can access written path.

I tried like this -

```
    var file_path = models[this.file][this.file_type];
```

For example - if file is **bmw** & file_type is **obj**. it should return **assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.obj**.

But I am getting an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined.

**Kindly Help/Guide.**

Comment: See the working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrrabt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I logged in file & file_type in ngOnInit(). I can see correct values. but when i am looging file_path, its undefined.

Comment: its working ! thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine check out snippet below

```js
var models={
       "bmw":{
          "mtl":"assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.mtl",
          "obj":"assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.obj"
       },
       "bugatti":{
          "mtl":"assets/bugatti/bugatti.mtl",
          "obj":"assets/bugatti/bugatti.obj"
       }
    };
    
    var file="bmw";
    var fileType="obj";
    
    console.log(models[file][fileType])
```

Reason of your problem might be your `this.file` may not exist in your models for example if you set file="xyz" in above code you will get the same error for that you can check if file exist or not something like

```
var file_path =models[file] ? models[file][fileType] : null;
```

Comment: `console.log("file path", file_path); // null` but i checked file & file_type are there. even i checked for bmw also.

Comment: can you create a reproducible demo of your problem like stackblitz

Comment: Still struggling to run on local machine. could there be any other issue ? like version ? or anything ?

Comment: `console.log(this.file)` and `console.log(models)` and check what's print in console

Comment: `console.log('models : ', models);` is - `models :  
Module {default: {…}, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
default:
bmw: {mtl: "assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.mtl", obj: "assets/bmw/BMW X5 4.obj"}
bugatti: {mtl: "assets/bugatti/bugatti.mtl", obj: "assets/bugatti/bugatti.obj"}
__proto__: Object
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true`

Comment: `console.log('file ', this.file); ` is - `file :  bmw`

Comment: this is something wrong with your model and file make sure model is an object and file is a string bcs your out showing something else it should look like https://prnt.sc/pjvipq

Comment: `console.log('model file : ', models[this.file]);` is `model file :  undefined`

Comment: `console.log('type of file : ', typeof(this.file);` is  `type of file :  string`

Comment: type of fine is string but your models is not what you have show about it's something module.check for your model if that's correct

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, I didn't understand. how to do this module.check.

Comment: your models contains wrong data can get the screenshot of console and post here or just try to fix your models

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur glad it helped